# How do we sort Repositories in GDB workbench?

Tags: graphdb

When we click on 'Repositories' to choose one, the repositories are not sorted according to the creation date. Is there something we can do to sort repositories according to what date/time they were created?

There is another project in the house that is also using licensed GDB but GDB 9.1, and their repositories are sorted according to when they were created (newely created in the last). They didn't do anything special to achieve this. Is it relative to the newer version of GDB or some settings that can be tweaked?

We create Repos using RDF4J API, and are using 8.6.1 GDB licensed version.

Answer (score 1):

Got help. Repositories are sorted in Alphabetical order in the workbench. We had a random string in the beginning of Repo name that was casuing Repos to be random (but still they were correctly sorted Alphabeticaly).